# Generate all possible keys for 2 or more sets of strings in same order

Tags: java, java-8, set, combinations, key-generator

There are **N** sets with **M** values in each. How to generate all possible combination in given order of sets efficiently?.

```
SetA = {'A', 'B'}
SetB = {'x', 'Y'}
SetC = {'L', 'M'}
```

**Key Order**  = `SetA_SetB_SetC`

**Output :**

```
A_X_L, A_X_M, A_Y_L, A_Y_M, B_X_L, B_X_M, B_Y_L, B_Y_M
```

Comment: Show some effort on your part..! The least you can do is add a brute force approach of iterating all sets to generate all possible combinations and maybe then ask for help optimizing the solution...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Java-8 onwards use [#Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), I have implemented the code below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class CandidateCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> ListA = Arrays.asList("A", "B");
        List<String> ListX = Arrays.asList("X", "Y");
        List<String> ListL = Arrays.asList("L", "M");
        List<String> collect = ListA.stream().flatMap(a -> ListX.stream().flatMap(x -> ListL.stream().map(l -> a + "_" + x + "_" + l))).collect(Collectors.toList());
        collect.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A_X_L
A_X_M
A_Y_L
A_Y_M
B_X_L
B_X_M
B_Y_L
B_Y_M
```

Comment: Java 8 added the stream API which has been part of every subsequent JDK version. Recommending Java 8 implies that the stream API only exists in Java 8. I propose that you [edit] your answer and recommend using the stream API which is available in all Java versions since Java 8.

Comment: Instead of collecting to a list, you could use Collectors.joining(", ") so it would give the same result as OP is expecting.

Comment: @Abra , It is always forward compatible in S/W Industry but anyhow I accept your recommendations.